# Connection timed out NGINX php-fpm mail()

Tags: nginx, postfix, php-fpm

I am porting a PHP site from an Apache server too a NGINX server. First I will get rid of `apache` to avoid any problems:

```
# service httpd stop
# yum erase httpd*
```

Now I am going to install `php-fpm` so I can extend php functions through NGINX:

```
# yum install php-fpm
```

Let's make sure php-fpm is running under the right user:

```
# ps aux | grep apache
apache    1658  0.0  0.5 222552  5316 ?        S    20:41   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
apache    1659  0.0  1.0 227268 10536 ?        S    20:41   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
apache    1660  0.0  1.0 227268 10420 ?        S    20:41   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
apache    1661  0.0  1.0 227268 10420 ?        S    20:41   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
apache    1662  0.0  0.5 222552  5316 ?        S    20:41   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
```

Nope... so what if:

```
# vi /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
# service php-fpm restart
# ps aux | grep nginx   
nginx     2379  0.0  0.3 222264  3504 ?        S    21:47   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx     2380  0.0  0.3 222264  3504 ?        S    21:47   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx     2381  0.0  0.3 222264  3504 ?        S    21:47   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx     2382  0.0  0.3 222264  3504 ?        S    21:47   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx     2383  0.0  0.3 222264  3508 ?        S    21:47   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
```

Fantastic... Let's see what happens when I invoke a `mail()` call from my app:

```
postfix/pickup[2305]: 6B9B6223BD: uid=497 from=<nginx>
postfix/cleanup[2393]: 6B9B6223BD: message-id=<20130318014941.6B9B6223BD@penny.localdomain>
postfix/qmgr[2306]: 6B9B6223BD: from=<nginx@penny.localdomain>, size=367, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
postfix/smtp[2396]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.75.26]:25: Connection timed out
postfix/smtp[2396]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.65.26]:25: Connection timed out
postfix/smtp[2396]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.70.27]:25: Connection timed out
postfix/smtp[2396]: connect to alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.69.27]:25: Connection timed out
postfix/smtp[2396]: connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.71.26]:25: Connection timed out
postfix/smtp[2396]: 6B9B6223BD: to=<myemail@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=151, delays=0.03/0.01/150/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.71.26]:25: Connection timed out)
```

So can my box actually figure out how to reach gmail?

```
# host -t mx gmail.com
gmail.com mail is handled by 20 alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com mail is handled by 30 alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com mail is handled by 40 alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com mail is handled by 5 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com mail is handled by 10 alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
```

It sure can.. hummm..

Let me note this is a guest Centos 6.3 VM running locally.

***The problem is that I am not able to deliver mail using the current configuration.***

I'm not sure what to do next at this point, any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Connect the machine to the Internet. If you _think_ it is connected, you need to check again, because it clearly is having issues here.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Haha I wish that was it.

Comment: You DID check again, right?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I triple checked. `#curl google.com` `#ping google.com` I even `#yum erase php*` `#yum install php php-fpm` and went through the bases one more time. There must be more to this.

Comment: WHat about `telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25`?

Comment: @Josh Humm... Hangs at `Trying 173.194.73.27...` followed by `Network is unreachable`. However my iptables include `-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: Seems to me that your ISP is blocking outgoing port 25 traffic. Can you `telnet df02.sitepalette.com 25`?

Comment: @Josh Tried on local box and got same thing. Tried on a remote box out in space and it worked. Looks like my ISP is dickhead. A good follow up question to this though is why does mail get through using apache?

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though my ISP was blocking outbound traffic on port 25. I was able to confirm this by comparing a connection to:

```
telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25
```

on my local box and a remote box outside of the ISP. The remote box was able to make a connection.

At least *I think* that's whats going on.

Comment: Yeah that's what I suspected also... Many ISPs do this in order to limit SPAM. Ask if they have an MTA you can use and configure postfix to use a `relayhost`